# Are there missable achievements/trophies in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm getting started on Mass Effect 3 and I'd like to know whether there are missable achievements (Xbox 36) or trophies (PS3) from the get-go. You know, instead of finding out there was one and I blew past it and have to restart the game to get it.

**Are there missable achievements/trophies in Mass Effect 3?**

Comment: I believe achievements/trophies should be identical on all platforms (save possibly for the PS3 having a Platinum) so this probably doesn't need to be so specific.

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The Freedom Fighter achievement, which comes with the From Ashes DLC, is easily missable. You must activate 3 consoles on Eden Prime before the mission ends, and you cannot return there once you complete the mission. Insanity is obviously an easy one to miss, if you left Earth at any other difficulty than Insane you'll have to start over. Most other achievements seem to either be do X a number of times or just checkpoints along the story's path.